# Problem with asbestos sheet roof

Tags: home

In my home, I have put asbestos sheet on the roof of my house. In some places I found it to be broken like this . how can I repair this using home made things? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hire a professional hazmat specialist to deal with the asbestos.  Without proper training and equipment, you will likely expose yourself and others to the microscopic fibers that can lead to health problems, including cancer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess with asbestos without a hazmat suit or proper training. That being said, you can a) seal it off with plastic sheets and tape or b) use varnish to seal it up. If you use varnish, don't put so much that it adds a lot of weight while wet. If it sags and falls off, the fresh break will release more barbed mineral fibers that can get stuck in your lungs causing sustained inflammation that leads to DNA mutation and cancer in 20 years.